# Read 3 bytes from VISA using Labview

Tags: microcontroller, labview, visa

I am new in Labview. I have to implement a program that can read 3 bytes from a Microcontroller: The first one should be from a command table (I've already done that), the second one should be a number, and the third one should be a CRC value.

I managed to do the first byte, but I don't know how to add the other bytes in my program.

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here.

The following example reads a single byte first, and then another two bytes.

The *VISA* read functions always return strings, but there is a *String To Bytearray* function, which is used to get the two bytes as numeric values:

[image]